Error declaring exchange type 'x-delayed-message' in RabbitMQ with Docker Compose
I'm trying to set up delayed message functionality using the 'rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange' plugin in RabbitMQ running within Docker Compose. However, I'm encountering an error when my application attempts to declare an exchange of type x-delayed-message.
I analyzed the error messages you provided, which indicated an incompatibility between the desired exchange type (x-delayed-message) and the RabbitMQ version. Based on that analysis, I offered several solutions:
Dockerfile
FROM rabbitmq:3.9.15

# Enable RabbitMQ Management Plugin
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management

# Download the plugin file locally
ADD https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/3.12.0/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.12.0.ez /tmp/

# Enable the Delayed Message Exchange Plugin
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange

# Clean up
RUN rm /tmp/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.12.0.ez

Error:
Error on AMQP connection <0.812.0> (172.26.0.1:52022 -> 172.26.0.3:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest', state: running), channel 1:

operation exchange.declare caused a connection exception command_invalid: "unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message'"

Verify RabbitMQ version compatibility with the plugin.
Double-check plugin enablement within the RabbitMQ container.
Explore alternative approaches for delayed messaging if version upgrade isn't feasible.
My goal was to help you troubleshoot the error and achieve delayed message functionality in your application.
